# Understanding Scanner's findWithinHorizon method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use and understand Java's [`Scanner#findWithinHorizon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon(java.util.regex.Pattern,%20int)) method.

I have written following piece of code which uses this method but I am not able to understand how it is working.

```
 private static void findWithinHorizon() {
    String string = "Balkrishan Nagpal --> 1111, 2222, 3333";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern) = " + scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 26));
    }
}
```

When I run the above method, I get the following output

```
scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern) = 1111
scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern) = 2222
scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern) = 3333
```

but I would expect output to contain only

```
scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern) = 1111
```

as I have provided the horizon value as 26.

My understanding is that while finding the matching result scanner won't go beyond index 26 in the string.

Can someone please explain how this is working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon(java.util.regex.Pattern,%20int)) it behaves as expected:

> This method searches through the input up to the specified search horizon, ignoring delimiters. If the pattern is found the scanner **advances past the input that matched** and returns the string that matched the pattern. If no such pattern is detected then the null is returned and the scanner's position remains unchanged. This method may block waiting for input that matches the pattern.
>
> A scanner will never search more than horizon code points **beyond its current position**.

After successfully finding `1111` the position is advanced to just after that match. The next `findWithinHorizon` call searches through a maximum of 26 characters after the first match.

---

`scanner.hasNext()` returns true if there is something else than whitespace after the
current position. `scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 26)` then searches the next 26
characters for the pattern and returns it (at the same time advancing the current
position to just after the match).

So your code proceeds as follows:

- Creating the scanner: the current position is `0`.
- `scanner.hasNext()` returns true, since the string contains not only whitespace.
- `scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 26)` searches for the pattern in the position range from 0 to 26, finds `1111` at positions 22 to 25, sets the new position to 26 and returns `1111`
- `scanner.hasNext()` returns true, since the string starting at position 26 contains not only whitespace
- `scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 26)` searches for the pattern in the position range 26 to 52, finds `2222` at positions 28 to 31, sets the new position to 32 and returns `2222`
- and so on...

Comment: so does it mean, after it finds numbers, it still look for 26 characters after that and stop searching for pattern?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama The scanner stops searching immediately, at the position right after where it found the match. But your code is in a `while` loop, so it gets executed multiple times, and advances each time. `scanner.hasNext()` returns true as long as there is more data available to read. Since the scanner stops after the match, rather than at the end of the string, there's still more data to be read after it finds `1111`.

Comment: @ThomasKläger thanks for the detailed explanation. if you see the code and run it.. it print 3333 for the third loop. So when you say  in second loop it scans from 26 to 52, it should have printed both 2222 and 3333 isnt it? What i feel is.. since scanner is separated by space till the condition is false the keeps finding the pattern isnt it?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama your pattern matches consecutive digits, and in the second loop iteration the only sequence of consecutive digits that can be found is `2222`. After that the input string contains a comma (`,`) which is not matched by your pattern and  so the search terminates.